# C# JSON Error converting value 3072 to type 'WeatherUnderground.RootObject'

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize json from here :

https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?MR=1

I am de-serializing this way :

```
RootObject oData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse.ContentString);
```

I have used http://jsonutils.com/ to create my C# classes.

```
    public class Features
{
    public int hourly10day { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string termsofService { get; set; }
    public Features features { get; set; }
}

public class FCTTIME
{
    public string hour { get; set; }
    public string hour_padded { get; set; }
    public string min { get; set; }
    public string min_unpadded { get; set; }
    public string sec { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string mon { get; set; }
    public string mon_padded { get; set; }
    public string mon_abbrev { get; set; }
    public string mday { get; set; }
    public string mday_padded { get; set; }
    public string yday { get; set; }
    public string isdst { get; set; }
    public string epoch { get; set; }
    public string pretty { get; set; }
    public string civil { get; set; }
    public string month_name { get; set; }
    public string month_name_abbrev { get; set; }
    public string weekday_name { get; set; }
    public string weekday_name_night { get; set; }
    public string weekday_name_abbrev { get; set; }
    public string weekday_name_unlang { get; set; }
    public string weekday_name_night_unlang { get; set; }
    public string ampm { get; set; }
    public string tz { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string UTCDATE { get; set; }
}

public class Temp
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Dewpoint
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Wspd
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Wdir
{
    public string dir { get; set; }
    public string degrees { get; set; }
}

public class Windchill
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Heatindex
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Feelslike
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Qpf
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Snow
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class Mslp
{
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string metric { get; set; }
}

public class HourlyForecast
{
    public FCTTIME FCTTIME { get; set; }
    public Temp temp { get; set; }
    public Dewpoint dewpoint { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string icon_url { get; set; }
    public string fctcode { get; set; }
    public string sky { get; set; }
    public Wspd wspd { get; set; }
    public Wdir wdir { get; set; }
    public string wx { get; set; }
    public string uvi { get; set; }
    public string humidity { get; set; }
    public Windchill windchill { get; set; }
    public Heatindex heatindex { get; set; }
    public Feelslike feelslike { get; set; }
    public Qpf qpf { get; set; }
    public Snow snow { get; set; }
    public string pop { get; set; }
    public Mslp mslp { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public IList<HourlyForecast> hourly_forecast { get; set; }
}
```

but I am still getting :

> Error converting value 3072 to type 'WeatherUnderground.RootObject'. -    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(Object value, Type targetType)

What am I doing wrong ?
Also, I am using .NET 3.5 if that has anything to do with this.

Thanks

Comment: Report the json that are you getting, the link that you have posted refer to documentation

Comment: here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/77oiems4z5v5cgf/json.txt?dl=0

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error for the json and classes given

Comment: You see this issue because you C# class is not matching with JSON data. Try to use this site, it take 5s to have the class you want http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Features
{
    public int conditions { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string termsofService { get; set; }
    public Features features { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
}

public class DisplayLocation
{
    public string full { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string state_name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string country_iso3166 { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string elevation { get; set; }
}

public class ObservationLocation
{
    public string full { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string country_iso3166 { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string elevation { get; set; }
}

public class Estimated
{
}

public class CurrentObservation
{
    public Image image { get; set; }
    public DisplayLocation display_location { get; set; }
    public ObservationLocation observation_location { get; set; }
    public Estimated estimated { get; set; }
    public string station_id { get; set; }
    public string observation_time { get; set; }
    public string observation_time_rfc822 { get; set; }
    public string observation_epoch { get; set; }
    public string local_time_rfc822 { get; set; }
    public string local_epoch { get; set; }
    public string local_tz_short { get; set; }
    public string local_tz_long { get; set; }
    public string local_tz_offset { get; set; }
    public string weather { get; set; }
    public string temperature_string { get; set; }
    public double temp_f { get; set; }
    public double temp_c { get; set; }
    public string relative_humidity { get; set; }
    public string wind_string { get; set; }
    public string wind_dir { get; set; }
    public int wind_degrees { get; set; }
    public double wind_mph { get; set; }
    public string wind_gust_mph { get; set; }
    public double wind_kph { get; set; }
    public string wind_gust_kph { get; set; }
    public string pressure_mb { get; set; }
    public string pressure_in { get; set; }
    public string pressure_trend { get; set; }
    public string dewpoint_string { get; set; }
    public int dewpoint_f { get; set; }
    public int dewpoint_c { get; set; }
    public string heat_index_string { get; set; }
    public string heat_index_f { get; set; }
    public string heat_index_c { get; set; }
    public string windchill_string { get; set; }
    public string windchill_f { get; set; }
    public string windchill_c { get; set; }
    public string feelslike_string { get; set; }
    public string feelslike_f { get; set; }
    public string feelslike_c { get; set; }
    public string visibility_mi { get; set; }
    public string visibility_km { get; set; }
    public string solarradiation { get; set; }
    public string UV { get; set; }
    public string precip_1hr_string { get; set; }
    public string precip_1hr_in { get; set; }
    public string precip_1hr_metric { get; set; }
    public string precip_today_string { get; set; }
    public string precip_today_in { get; set; }
    public string precip_today_metric { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string icon_url { get; set; }
    public string forecast_url { get; set; }
    public string history_url { get; set; }
    public string ob_url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public CurrentObservation current_observation { get; set; }
}
```

Json:

```
{
"response": {
    "version": "0.1",
    "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
    "features": {
        "conditions": 1
    }
},
"current_observation": {
    "image": {
        "url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title": "Weather Underground",
        "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
    },
    "display_location": {
        "full": "San Francisco, CA",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "state_name": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "country_iso3166": "US",
        "zip": "94101",
        "latitude": "37.77500916",
        "longitude": "-122.41825867",
        "elevation": "47.00000000"
    },
    "observation_location": {
        "full": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California",
        "city": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "country_iso3166": "US",
        "latitude": "37.773285",
        "longitude": "-122.417725",
        "elevation": "49 ft"
    },
    "estimated": {},
    "station_id": "KCASANFR58",
    "observation_time": "Last Updated on June 27, 5:27 PM PDT",
    "observation_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:13 -0700",
    "observation_epoch": "1340843233",
    "local_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:14 -0700",
    "local_epoch": "1340843234",
    "local_tz_short": "PDT",
    "local_tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "local_tz_offset": "-0700",
    "weather": "Partly Cloudy",
    "temperature_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
    "temp_f": 66.3,
    "temp_c": 19.1,
    "relative_humidity": "65%",
    "wind_string": "From the NNW at 22.0 MPH Gusting to 28.0 MPH",
    "wind_dir": "NNW",
    "wind_degrees": 346,
    "wind_mph": 22.0,
    "wind_gust_mph": "28.0",
    "wind_kph": 35.4,
    "wind_gust_kph": "45.1",
    "pressure_mb": "1013",
    "pressure_in": "29.93",
    "pressure_trend": "+",
    "dewpoint_string": "54 F (12 C)",
    "dewpoint_f": 54,
    "dewpoint_c": 12,
    "heat_index_string": "NA",
    "heat_index_f": "NA",
    "heat_index_c": "NA",
    "windchill_string": "NA",
    "windchill_f": "NA",
    "windchill_c": "NA",
    "feelslike_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
    "feelslike_f": "66.3",
    "feelslike_c": "19.1",
    "visibility_mi": "10.0",
    "visibility_km": "16.1",
    "solarradiation": "",
    "UV": "5",
    "precip_1hr_string": "0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
    "precip_1hr_in": "0.00",
    "precip_1hr_metric": " 0",
    "precip_today_string": "0.00 in (0 mm)",
    "precip_today_in": "0.00",
    "precip_today_metric": "0",
    "icon": "partlycloudy",
    "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
    "forecast_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html",
    "history_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KCASANFR58/2012/6/27/DailyHistory.html",
    "ob_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=37.773285,-122.417725"
    }
}
```

Your json and Class structure will be like this.

Its giving me proper results when doing like this.

```
RootObject oData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse.ContentString);
```